# Error using pg_upgrade going from PostgreSQL 10 to 12

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgresql-12, pg-upgrade

I have an installation of PostgreSQL 10, and just installed PostgreSQL 12 (on Windows). I'm trying to migrate over the databases using `pg_upgrade`. However, I'm getting an annoying error:

The command I ran was as follows:

```
$ pg_upgrade.exe -b 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\' -B 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\
' -d 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data\' -D 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\'
```

However, I get the error message:

```
You must identify the directory where the new cluster binaries reside.
Please use the -B command-line option or the PGBINNEW environment variable.
Failure, exiting
```

... despite clearly doing so.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes, or doubling the backslashes? (MS-widows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the "For Windows users .." users section in step "9) Run pg_upgrade" at [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html):

> For Windows users, you must be logged into an administrative account, and then start a shell as the postgres user and set the proper path:
>
> ```
> RUNAS /USER:postgres "CMD.EXE"
> SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin;
> ```
>
> and then run pg_upgrade with quoted directories, e.g.:
>
> ```
> pg_upgrade.exe
>    --old-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data"
>    --new-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/data"
>    --old-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin"
>    --new-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin"
> ```